# How can I see if my app is visible to tablets and ICS in the Amazon Market

Tags: android, google-play

I can see my application in the Amazon market, but someone told me they can't see it using Ice Cream Sandwich. Also, I think it is not visible on Android tablets.

How can I see what those (ICS and Tablet) users see in the Android Market?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your Google Play Store developer console, click on the name of your app, and scroll down to **Supported Devices** (it's the last heading underneath Publishing Options).

You should see something along the lines of

> This application is available to over 1172 devices. Show devices

Click on Show Devices and you'll be able to see exactly what devices can and can't see your app.